# Why does Leaflet handle .addLayer() function differently between FeatureGroups of Points vs other geometry types?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I've noticed that adding a `FeatureGroup` to the `map` object via `.addLayer()` performs differently for `FeatureCollections` of `Point` vs other types of geometry and it makes it difficult to remove `FeatureGroup`s from the map sufficiently. Using `.addLayer()` for a `FeatureGroup` of 2 points results in 3 layers being added to the private `._layers` property on the `map` object. Any other geometry type (with 2 features in this particular test) will result in 4 layers being added to the `._layers` property on the `map` object. In this case, if you go to then `map.removeLayer(<FeatureGroup instance>)`, it will only remove 3 layers, leaving the 4th one it added behind. **If this is expected Leaflet behavior, how do you keep track of the extra `L.Layer` type layer that gets added when you can't dynamically add a custom `id` property to it?**

Instantiate map with basemap

```
let map = L.map('map').setView([39.06862,-96.681679], 5);
let lite = L.tileLayer("http://{s}.sm.mapstack.stamen.com/(toner-lite,$fff[difference],$fff[@23],$fff[hsl-saturation@20])/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"); 
lite.addTo(map)
```

Determine number of layers initially on the map

```
console.log('Layer Count: ', Object.keys(map._layers).length)
//Layer Count: 1
```

Add `FeatureGroup` of 2 point features to the map

```
const points = {
        "type":"FeatureCollection",
        "features": [
          {
            "type": "Point", 
            "coordinates": [30.0, 10.0]
          },
          {
            "type": "Point", 
            "coordinates": [20.0, 40.0]
          }
        ]
      }

let pointLayer = L.geoJSON(points, {
        style: function (feature) {
          return {
            //stuff
          };
        }
});
pointLayer.id = 'pointLayer'

console.log('FeatureGroup Layer Count: ', Object.keys(pointLayer._layers).length)
//FeatureGroup Layer Count: 2

map.addLayer(pointLayer);
console.log('Layer Count: ', Object.keys(map._layers).length)
//Layer Count: 4

console.log(Object.keys(map._layers))
//[25, 82, 83, 84]
```

ID `25` is the basemap. IDs `82` and `84` are of `L.Layer` type and contain one Point in each. ID `83` aggregates IDs `82` and `84` in its private `._layers` property and is of `L.FeatureGroup` type.

Remove the `FeatureGroup` and you should be left only with the basemap layer. This performs as expected.

```
map.eachLayer(function(layer){
  if (layer.id == 'pointLayer') {
    map.removeLayer(layer)
  }
})

console.log('Layer Count: ', Object.keys(map._layers).length)
//Layer Count: 1

console.log(Object.keys(map._layers))
//[25] (25 is the basemap)
```

Repeat the process but use a `FeatureGroup` of LineStrings instead (remove the points layer you added to the map first, so you're starting with only the basemap layer):

```
const lines = {
        "type":"FeatureCollection",
        "features": [
          {
            "type": "LineString", 
            "coordinates": [
                [30.0, 10.0],
                [10.0, 30.0],
                [40.0, 40.0]
            ]
          },
          {
            "type": "LineString", 
            "coordinates": [
                [50.0, 60.0],
                [10.0, 20.0],
                [20.0, 30.0]
            ]
          }
        ]
}

let lineLayer = L.geoJSON(lines, {
        style: function (feature) {
          //stuff
          };
        }
});
lineLayer.id = 'lineLayer'

console.log('FeatureGroup Layer Count: ', Object.keys(lineLayer._layers).length)
//FeatureGroup Layer Count: 2

map.addLayer(lineLayer);
console.log('Layer Count: ', Object.keys(map._layers).length)
//Layer Count: 5

console.log(Object.keys(map._layers))
//[25, 82, 83, 84, 85]
```

The last `console.log` statement produces ID `25` as the basemap, IDs `82` and `84` are each `L.Layer` type layer and contain one `Point` each, ID `83` is the `L.FeatureGroup` layer that aggregates IDs `82` and `84` inside its private `._layers` property, and ID `85` is some other `L.Layer` layer that aggregates the IDs `82` and `84` inside its private `._layers` property. I can't figure out why its generated or what its for and removing the `FeatureGroup` layer from the `map` does not delete that layer, making it hard to cleanup. **How do you keep track of these additional types of layers for cleanup?**

If you remove the `lineLayer` from the `map`, you are left with a remnant layer for some reason.

```
map.eachLayer(function(layer){
  if (layer.id == 'lineLayer') {
    map.removeLayer(layer)
  }
})

console.log('Layer Count: ', Object.keys(map._layers).length)
//Layer Count: 2

console.log(Object.keys(map._layers))
//[25, 85]
```

I have been able to replicate this behavior using `MultiPolygon`s too. I have not tried other geometry types, but I believe they would act the same given the structure of the `coordinates` property of a feature is similar between all other geometry types outside of `Point`s.